# how can I stop weird scrolling jump behavior with multiple mat-select checkbox clicks?

Tags: angular-material, mat-select

I have a material multi-select and noticed that if I have content before my `mat-option` tags, then clicking on them causes the scroll bar to jump to odd places causing incredibly confusing behavior...  I have replicated the issue with stackblitz and am hoping someone can shed some light as far as why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Simply click the select drop down and scroll to some options and check some of them and you will notice as you click the pane's scroll position will obnoxiously jump around...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14-material-uoxt1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html

Comment: Facing the same issue but didn't any answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Stackblitz link is not working so I don't know if you are doing stuff with the CSS.

If you are setting the mat-options height manually - then you will have scrolling bugs. The angular material team states that:

> all our calculations are based around a certain height for the options.

in this link: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8054